# Auth::attempt() in laravel 4.2 proper usage

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

im trying to use Auth::attempt($credentials) in my controller and here is my sample code

```
$credentials= [
        'SystemUserName'       => Input::get('username'),
        'SystemUserPassword'   => Input::get('password')
    ];
```

then im having a error saying `Undefined Index: Password` only to know that i can use any field for username but i can't do that for the password because it should be 'password'. the thing is `SystemUserName` and `SystemUserPassword` are column names in my database. How can i do this properly? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can use only the `'password'` column name with the included `database` and `eloquent` drivers, because the column name is hardcoded in the user provider. So your only bet is to create your own custom driver by extending the Eloquent one. This can be done in four easy steps as explained below:

**1.** Create your custom driver class file in `app/extensions/CustomUserProvider.php` file with the following contents:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface;

class MyCustomUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        $query = $this->createModel()->newQuery();

        foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != 'SystemUserPassword') $query->where($key, $value);
        }

        return $query->first();
    }

    public function validateCredentials(UserInterface $user, array $credentials)
    {
        return $this->hasher->check($credentials['SystemUserPassword'], $user->SystemUserPassword);
    }
}
```

**2.** Add `"app/extensions"` to your `composer.json` in the `classmap` section:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/extensions" // <-- add this line here
    ]
},
```

Then run a `php composer dump-autoload`.

**3.** In your `app/start/global.php` file add this to register your custom driver:

```
Auth::extend('mydriver', function($app)
{
    return new MyCustomUserProvider($app['hash'], Config::get('auth.model'));
});
```

**4.** Then just set the driver in your `app/config/auth.php` to this:

```
'driver' => 'mydriver',
```

This was tested and it works just fine.

---

Mind you, this will work assuming your user passwords were hashed with the `Hash::make()` method Laravel offers and stored that way in the database. If not, then you need to adjust the `validateCredentials` method in `MyCustomUserProvider` with your own compare method between the plain and hashed password.